# Fragment being created despite not being in the layout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm following the tutorial here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating and am receiving a crash when I rotate the device to landscape, then portrait, then back to landscape. The crash occurs in the following snippet.

```
public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
    ArticleFragment articleFrag = (ArticleFragment)
   getSupportFragmentManager()
       .findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);

        if (articleFrag != null) {
         // Crash happens here.
            articleFrag.updateArticleView(position);
        } else {
         //...
        }
    }
}
```

The reason for this is that when the app is rotated back to portrait, the fragment manager is returning a fragment despite it not being present in the portrait layout. To investigate this, I created a small app containing a horizontal layout like the following:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <fragment android:name="com.example.matt.personfragments.PersonListFragment"
          android:id="@+id/person_list"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment android:name="com.example.matt.personfragments.PersonDetailFragment"
          android:id="@+id/person_detail"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and a portrait layout like the following:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <fragment android:name="com.example.matt.personfragments.PersonListFragment"
          android:id="@+id/person_list"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I've overridden the constructor in both fragments to log their creation.
As expected, when the app is first created I see PersonListFragment being created. When I rotate the device I see both PersonListFragment and PersonDetailFragment. So far so normal.

However, when I rotate the device back to portrait I see both PersonListFragment and PersonDetailFragment being created again. I believe this is due to the fragment being present in the saved instant state. Is this correct, and if so does that mean that the tutorial is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among the things that the `Activity` will save (actually technically the activity's `FragmentManager`) during a configuration change (like rotation) is `Fragment`s.

Normally, this doesn't cause any issues, because the same fragments are used in any orientation. But in master/detail screens where the detail fragment is only visible in landscape orientation, you can run into problems.

Once the detail fragment has been created for the first time (when you rotate to landscape), that fragment will exist in the FragmentManager until you exit the activity. This is true even when you rotate back to portrait. However, the detail fragment will not be **added** in situations where your activity layout doesn't include that fragment.

So you can change your check from:

> ```
> if (articleFrag != null)
> ```

to

```
if (articleFrag != null && articleFrag.isAdded())
```